# nextjs - shopping cart problem with accurate cart total amount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, shopping-cart

I am building a shopping cart and having difficulty with total cart amount.
When I go to cart page total amount shows only the amount of last item added to the cart.

```
state = {
    cart: { items: [], total: 0 },
  };

addItem = (item) => {
    let { items } = this.state.cart;
    //check for item already in cart, if not found, increase quantity by 1
    const itemFound = items.find((i) => i.id === item.id);
    if (!itemFound) {
      item.quantity = 1;
      // console.log(this.state.cart.total, item.price);
      this.setState(
        {
          cart: {
            items: [...items, item],
            total: this.state.cart.total + item.price,
          },
        },
        () => Cookie.set("cart", this.state.cart.items)
      );
    } else {
      this.setState(
        {
          cart: {
            items: this.state.cart.items.map((item) =>
              item.id === itemFound.id
                ? Object.assign({}, item, { quantity: item.quantity + 1 })
                : item
            ),
            total: this.state.cart.total + item.price,
          },
        },
        () => Cookie.set("cart", this.state.cart.items)
      );
    }
  };
```

**UPDATE**
I found out the problem occurs when I manually navigate to cart page for eg: http://localhost:3000/cart

If I navigate to cart page via "next link", it shows correct total, however on page refresh it again shows the amount of last item added to cart as total amount
Below is how I am retrieving cart and setting state

```
componentDidMount() {
    const cart = Cookie.get("cart");
    //if items in cart, set items and total from cookie
    if (typeof cart === "string" && cart !== "undefined") {
      JSON.parse(cart).forEach((item) => {
        this.setState({
          cart: { items: JSON.parse(cart), total: item.price * item.quantity },
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

I am currently storing cart items in cookie, not total
There is something wrong with this approach and I am unable to figure it out.
Looking forward for guidance
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply the quantity of items with the corresponding price of that item to get the total price, before setting state.

Example :

```
let total = this.state.cart.items.reduce(
      (accumalatedQuantity, cartItem) =>
         accumalatedQuantity + cartItem.quantity * cartItem.price,
      0
   )
```

Comment: use localStorage rather than cookie to persist such data.